# Average of a 3D numpy slice based on 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, mean

I am trying to calculate the average of a 3D array between two indices on the 1st axis. The start and end indices vary from cell to cell and are represented by two separate 2D arrays that are the same shape as a slice of the 3D array.

I have managed to implement a piece of code that loops through the pixels of my 3D array, but this method is painfully slow in the case of my array with a shape of `(70, 550, 350)`. Is there a way to vectorise the operation using `numpy` or `xarray` (the arrays are stored in an `xarray` dataset)?

Here is a snippet of what I would like to optimise:

```py
# My 3D raster containing values; shape = (time, x, y)
values = np.random.rand(10, 55, 60)

# A 2D raster containing start indices for the averaging
start_index = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(values.shape[1], values.shape[2]))

# A 2D raster containing end indices for the averaging
end_index = np.random.randint(5, 9, size=(values.shape[1], values.shape[2]))

# Initialise an array that will contain results
mean_array = np.zeros_like(values[0, :, :])

# Loop over 3D raster to calculate the average between indices on axis 0
for i in range(0, values.shape[1]):
    for j in range(0, values.shape[2]):
        mean_array[i, j] = np.mean(values[start_index[i, j]: end_index[i, j], i, j], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this without loops is to zero-out the entries you don't want to use, compute the sum of the remaining items, then divide by the number of nonzero entries. For example:

```python
i = np.arange(values.shape[0])[:, None, None]
mean_array_2 = np.where((i >= start_index) & (i < end_index), values, 0).sum(0) / (end_index - start_index)
np.allclose(mean_array, mean_array_2)
# True
```

Note that this assumes that the indices are in the range `0 <= i < values.shape[0]`; if this is not the case you can use `np.clip` or other means to standardize the indices before computation.

Comment: My values generally range from -10 to +10. If I understand correctly, I would have to normalise them from 0 to `values.shape[0]`, do the operation and convert the mean back to the initial range?

Comment: No, the values can be anything. It’s the start and end indices that have to be in range for the two approaches to produce equivalent results.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tested your code and it works well. It is much faster than looping (600x). Interestingly, it is 2x slower than looping using numba jit. But that being said, it is the same order of magnitude, and as it was pointed out to me, nuba is harder to debug when it throws an error.